# Reading .xyz file into array(s)

Tags: arrays, fortran, fortran90

I've currently created a code that can open a file from an in putted directory, then begin sorting that data into two different arrays, an integer and a character. The input file looks like this:

```
1817
Plot50.0.xyz
  C        0.70900        0.00000        0.00000
  C        0.00000        1.22802        0.00000
  C        2.12700        0.00000        0.00000
  C        2.83600        1.22802        0.00000
  C        4.96300        0.00000        0.00000
  C        4.25400        1.22802        0.00000
  C        6.38100        0.00000        0.00000
  C        7.09000        1.22802        0.00000
  C        9.21700        0.00000        0.00000
  C        8.50800
```

[datafile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCWix.jpg)

Now I'm not sure if maybe I haven't allocated everything correctly when opening the file (format etc) but here is the code [working]:

```
program test01

character(len=40)    :: filename           !Storing the file name
character(len=20)    :: nam                !Collecting the file name within the file
integer(8)           :: N                  !Number of coordinates within the file
real(8), allocatable :: coa(:,:)           !Array containing xyz coordinates
character(len=6), allocatable :: atom(:,:) !Array containing the atomic make up
integer(8)           :: i,j,k              !Do loop parameters

    filename = '' 
    write (6,*) 'Enter file name' 
    read (5,*) filename 
    open (10, file=filename, status='OLD') 
    write (6,*) 'Sucessfully opened file:', filename 
    read(10,*) N

    allocate (coa(N,4))
    allocate (atom(N,1))
    read (10,*) nam
        print*, nam

        i = 0
        do while (i < N)
            read(10,*) atom(i,1), coa(i,2:4)
            i = i+1  
        end do

    print*, atom(0,1), atom(1,1), atom(4,1), atom(1818,1) !checking
    print*, coa(0,2), coa(1500,3)                         !checking   
    close (10) 

end program test01
```

So my main question lies with, are there any better ways to create the arrays (needs to be two as I believe characters and real cannot be mixed, and the `coa` array while be used for calculations later on) and specifically extract certain data from the file (more so to skip the row 2 of the file instead of inserting it into a character to remove it as it was causing all the issues when I was trying to create the arrays).

Comment: Welcome. Please insert the datafile as text. The picture is not acceptable. Please read [ask]

Comment: If the code is working, consider whether it is more on-topic  at http://codereview.stackexchange.com instead. Don't ask at both sites.

Comment: And if you are very new to Fortran please consider not using `real(8)` and `integer(8)`, it is a code smell and it is not portable to all compilers. It does not mean 8-byte variables. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/fortran/939/data-types/4390/precision-of-floating-point-numbers#t=201701280943571374653   Similarly, do not use `read(5,*)` and `write(6,*)`, but `(*,*)`. All of these advices would be better on-topic at the http://codereview.stackexchange.com site...

Comment: I did go through it, I'm just not sure how to upload the text file is all, as this is my first post very new to it all. And wasn't sure if it was viable to use a third party. Also, I did no even know of the existence of the other site. 

Oh just my lecturer who I will be working within the next 6 weeks gave me a small run down and wanted me to put the integers and real as 8 bit for now.

Comment: Would it be wise to remove this post and change to the codereview.stackexchange.com side of things?

Comment: You already have an answer here, keep it here, also it actually does have a bug. Text data is cut and paste directly into the question and the `{}` icon is used to format it properly. It does not have to be always complete, first 10 or 20 rows often suffices.

Comment: why dimension `coa(N,4)` then not use the first position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write *are there any better ways to create the arrays*.  Let's start with a correct way, which this isn't ...

```
i = 0
do while (i < N)
    read(10,*) atom(i,1), coa(i,2:4)
    i = i+1  
end do
```

That looks to be like a C loop (`for (i=0; i<N; i++)` ) written in Fortran and it makes the mistake of starting indexing into the arrays at row `0`.  Since the code makes no effort to start the array indexes at `0`, and Fortran defaults to indexing from `1`, the first execution of the `read` will read data into memory locations outside the extent of the arrays.

A correct and more Fortranic way would be

```
do i = 1, N
    read(10,*) atom(i,1), coa(i,2:4)
end do
```

I see that elsewhere you've printed values from row `0` of the arrays.  You got 'lucky' that those outside-the-bounds accesses don't go to addresses outside the program's address space and lead to segmentation faults.

The program is broken, it's just that it's only a little broken and hasn't caused you any pain yet.

Comment: Yeah that's precisely why I wanted to ask the question cause I was sure I wasn't doing things as standard and was just kind of playing around until it eventually shot out the values but there was an extra step caused by the zero, everything matches up a bit nicer now thanks.